# Sei o valor da variável, mas o switch só vai para o default

Tags: php, switch

Após uma pesquisa, eu obtenho o seguinte resultado:

```
           // O resultado desta linha é I ou II ou III;
           echo $subsecao;

           // O resultado desta linha é string;
           echo gettype($subsecao);

           // Faço um switch para atribuir um caso, mas, retorna apenas o default;

          switch ($subsecao){
            case "I":
              $subsecao = "1";
              break;
            case "II":
              $subsecao = "2";
              break;
            case "III":
              $subsecao = "3";
              break;    
           default:
              $subsecao = "Não encontrou";
          }

           // O resultado desta linha é "Não encontrou";
           echo $subsecao;

           // O resultado desta linha é string;
           echo gettype($subsecao);
```

Por que o `switch` não funciona com esse cenário?

Comment: Faz um `echo "::$subsecao::";` e vê se não tem nenhum espaço ai a mais.

Comment: Veja aqui a funcionar: http://ideone.com/VhdN7G

Comment: Neste valor echo "::$subsecao::";
deu este resultado ::I ::

neste echo $subsecao + "|";
deu este 0

Comment: Estás a passar um espaço a mais ali a seguir ao `I` estás a ver? O problema está ai Alê.

Comment: Porque `"I "` é diferente de `"I"`.

Comment: Para verificações assim, use o trim na variável antes de fazer o switch.

Comment: É osso, programação é muito show, mas, é osso.
:D.

Mas utilizei esta linha
$subsecao = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$arr[1]);

E retirou o espaço, mas, ainda cai para o default

Comment: Alê testou depois disso a ver se realmente está só o `I`?
Quando alguma coisa não funciona teste sempre os *inputs* e os *outputs* e se estiver tudo bem depois faça a verificação do código.

Comment: Antes do switch, agora esta mostrando assim:  
::I::,
mas depois do switch, está assim:
::Não encontrou::

Ele retirou o espaço, mas, ainda não casou no switch

Comment: Se já não tem espaço tem de funcionar. Experimenta com o `II`. Isso é mesmo um I de Igual ou é um l de lagarto?

Comment: tente `switch (trim($subsecao))`

Comment: Então @AlêMoraes resultou?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta e coloquei no final o caminho que fiz para chegar nessa variável, mas ainda, não funcionou.

Comment: (trim(strip_tags($subsecao)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar:

```
(trim(strip_tags($subsecao)))
```

Este código remove todas as tags HTML e remove todos os espaços a esquerda e direita do retorno da função, obs: o uso de strip_tags em HTML MAL formatado pode remover mais ou menos texto do que deveria tirar, há uma implementação não oficial neste [Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php) que é mais eficiente.

Comment: Funcionou!!! Ohhhhhhhhh

Comment: @AlêMoraes tenha cuidado que você não solucionou o problema, só deu uma volta nele. O problema está mesmo no que você recebe ali, que não deveria vir com espaços nem tags HTML.

Comment: @AlêMoraes, OK então sinalize que a resposta foi encontrada

Comment: Como sinalizo? Alterei a pergunta e o título, está certo?

Comment: seta Verde na lateral desta resposta e no triangulo

Comment: @AlêMoraes Não, o certo é colocar visto ao lado da resposta e tem a seta para cima para dar ponto positivo.

Comment: Fiz certo agora né?
Obrigado pela ajuda em tudo.

Comment: @AlêMoraes fez sim.

Comment: Ricardo, você saberia me dizer o porquê de ter que usar (trim(strip_tags($subsecao)))?

Comment: @AlêMoraes, a função `strip_tags` tem o objetivo de remover qualquer tag HTML que possa ter vindo junto com os valores do formulário (verifique XSS na internet) e o uso de `trim` é para remover os espaços ao lado esquerdo e direito da string que veio como valor de um formulário.

Answer (score 10):

Testei e funciona direitinho o seu código como pode ver [neste exemplo](http://ideone.com/VhdN7G) por isso o problema tem de estar no *input* que é passado para `$subsecao;`.

Faça `echo "::$subsecao::";` para verificar se o *input* está correto.

> Nota: Como disse e muito bem o @NovoK pode usar a função [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php)
>   para retirar os espaços `trim($subsecao);`

Comment: O resultado está assim

Seção I

echo "::$subsecao::";
    ::I::
echo $subsecao + "|";
    0

Depois do switch

echo "::$subsecao::";
    ::Não encontrou::
echo $subsecao + "|";
    0

Comment: O gettype antes e depois do switch está como string

Comment: @AlêMoraes Você está trazendo o valor de um GET?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta e coloquei no final o caminho que fiz para chegar nessa variável, mas ainda, não funcionou.

Comment: Funcionou com (trim(strip_tags($subsecao)))